# how to find all the records in has and belong to many join table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

this is the show method in my controllers i want to find all the `list` related to this `car`, and the relation between them is `has and belong to many`

```
def show
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: i have a join table between list_id and car_id, and i want to find all the list related to a particular car_id

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
class Car
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
class List
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end
```

then you can just call

```
@car =  Car.find(params[:id])
@lists = @car.lists
```

**Update**:

To create an unordered list of your `lists` you could do like this in your `cars/show.html.erb`:

```
<ul>
  <% @car.lists.each do |list| %>
    <li><%= link_to(list, list_path(list)) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes i have this in my relation
class Car
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
class List
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end
i am trying the code now

Comment: but how to show all these list in an array in the views : shows.html.erb page
i think this will give me an array for lists
will give an array with all the list ids found from the joint table ?

Comment: This should definitely give you an ActiveRecord::Relation. I can add a view example.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it like this,

```
def show
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  @lists = @car.lists
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered poor-quality content on Stack Overflow.  Please provide information about *why* this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

 def show
   @car = Car.find(params[:id])
   @lists = @car.lists
 end

end
```